# new Mongo connection causes server error

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx

In my CodeIgniter application (fresh install), the following line of code causes the page to show 'Server Error'

**controller:**

```
public function index()
{
  $m = new Mongo();
  echo 'Success';
}
```

If I comment out the `new Mongo()` line, everything works fine. I've ensured the Mongo process is running on the server.

I've even tried wrapping it in a `try/catch`, but I still get the server error.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing in my webserver (nginx) logs.

Comment: What about your PHP error logs?

Comment: Do you have a debugger installed? can you step through Mongo's constructor? Lastly, I have zero experience with Mongo, but I know some other ORM libs keep their own logs, or can be configured to log verbosely, perhaps even echo'ing what it's up to.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was really stupid on my part, and should have been the first thing I checked. The Mongo extension for PHP wasn't installed on my server. I did a `class_exists('Mongo')` to double check.